# VirtualBox - Windows 8 Host, UbuntuServer Guest

Tags: linux, interface, virtualbox

i want/need to have my webserver on a linux machine and i wanted to install UbuntuServer on my VirtualBox.
My only problem is to make the 2 system comunicate together.
If i select NAT, my Guest can surf the net, but i cant comunicate with the Host(nor SSH nether http), even if i set the 8888 port of the host with the 80 of the Guest and the 2222 with the 22.
If i select Bridged connection i can comunicate with the Guest throw its IP, but i cant seam to surf the net with the Guest. If i leave the DHCP i can, but of course i need a static IP, so for example if my Host is 192.168.0.x i edited with "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces"
something like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.y
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

But i cant ping my Host, Google ecc.

Comment: And where's the question about programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed ssh server in your ubuntu machine so that it can accept ssh connections ?

Install ssh server using 
https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Comment: Yes i did, cant even with the HTTP, the fact is that the port forwarding doesnt work. 
And i cant connect to the net if i set a static interfaces and not a DHCP one

Answer (score 0):

Just checked out with putty i can connect with SSH to "localhost" port 2222, but i cant really connect localhost:8080 to the webserver